C# .NET blazor mudblazor drag and drop problem
When I drag an item to a higher place(it means lower position index) its working fine(in the same Section), but if I try to a lower place(it means higher position index)(in the same Section) nothing happening.
MudCoantainer ItemDropped method:
private void ItemUpdated(MudItemDropInfo<DropZoneItem> dropItem)
{
    dropItem.Item.Zone = dropItem.DropzoneIdentifier;

    var indexOffset = _items.Count(x => x.Zone == dropItem.DropzoneIdentifier);

    var actualId = 0;
    if (Key == "edit" && dropItem.Item.Zone == "_header")
    {
        foreach (var item in _section)
        {
            if (item.DocumentId == doc.Id && item.Name == "_header")
            {
                actualId = item.Id;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (var actualSection in sections)
    {
        if (actualSection.DocumentId == doc.Id)
        {
            if (actualSection.Name == dropItem.DropzoneIdentifier)
            {
                actualId = actualSection.Id;
            }
        }
    }
    var itemToUpdate = _items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == dropItem.Item.Id);

    if (itemToUpdate != null)
    {            
        itemToUpdate.SectionId = actualId;
    }

    foreach (var item in sections)
    {
        if (dropItem.Item.Zone == item.Name)
        {
            dropItem.Item.SectionPosition = item.Position;
            dropItem.Item.SectionId = item.Id;
        }
    }

    _items.UpdateOrder(dropItem, item => item.Position, indexOffset);
    _items = _items.OrderBy(x => x.Position).Select(item => new DropZoneItem
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Zone = item.Zone,
            Name = item.Name,
            Type = item.Type,
            Description = item.Description,
            Position = item.Position,
            SectionId = item.SectionId,
            EnabledValue = item.EnabledValue,
            SectionPosition = item.SectionPosition
        })
    .ToList();
}

Note: I need this method, because i need to update _items list and something else.
I tried different ways, but i dont know whats the problem.
